# How to display the values of nested attributes in my views ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm starting with Ruby and i got some issue to display the infos in my views.

Here is my code:
e
*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :encrypted_password, :meta_attributes

  has_one :meta
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta
end
```

*app/controllers/users_controllers.rb*

```
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end
```

*app/views/users/index.html.rb*

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.meta.last_name %></td>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Has you expected, it returns some errors :

```
undefined method `last_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Do you have any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the line where you use

```
user.meta.last_name
```

It means that `user.meta` is `nil`.

If you are sure you add a `meta` to each user while creating them, the problem can come from the fact that `meta` is not in your `attr_accessible` list.

If you don't always create a `meta` for each user and you don't mind about having an empty `meta` you can add a callback to your `User` model:

```
before_create :add_meta

def add_meta
    if self.meta.nil?
        self.meta = Meta.create( put_your_default_attributes_here )
    end
end
```

Comment: `meta` is in my `attr_accessible list` :) All users will have meta, but some field should be empty. Is there a cleaner way to check if the fields are empty than `<% if user.meta %>`

Comment: @x4vier you would have to check for each field, for example for your last_name error, you could replace it by `user.meta.last_name if !user.meta.nil?` or something like that

Comment: @x4vier If all users have a non-nil meta you shouldn't be having the error you posted

Comment: yep, but that means one if for every field ? Isn't there a way to optimise this ?

Comment: @x4vier You can create your `meta` with default values for fields. You could use `last_name` defaults to `""` if no last_name is used. That way no field would be nil

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you've already solved this problem, but i had the same problem here, and solved putting the 'nil' method inside a conditional.  Maybe can help someone with the same problem.

```
<td>
  <% if user.meta %>
    <%= user.meta.last_name %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```